# How to put condition in CakePHP 3.2?

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

How do I put conditions in a query when fetching from the database in CakePHP 3.2.
Here I have implemented a pagination and it is easy to pass WHERE conditions (See code below).

```php
public $paginate = [
        'fields' => ['Users.id', 'Users.email', 'Users.name', 'Users.is_active'],
        'limit' => 1,
        'conditions'=>['Users.is_active' =>1],
        'order' => [
            'Users.id' => 'asc'
        ]
    ];

public function index() {
        $users = $this->paginate($this->Users);
        $this->set(compact('users'));
    }
```

In above code I have used pagination, so it's easy for me to pass conditions and other things like fields, order etc.

If the pagination is not present, then what will be the code? Here I only have to fetch the data from the database, then give conditions and other things.
In CakePHP 2.6 the code would be like below.

```php
  $this->EventCategory->find('all', array('conditions' => array('EventCategory.is_active' => 1), 'fields' => array('EventCategory.id', 'EventCategory.name')));
```

Is there any other way that I can do it like above (without pagination) in CakePHP 3.2?

Any proposals are welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest you start by reading the [CakePHP 3.x docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/contents.html) before proceeding to develop with it as a lot has changed especially with querying a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the docs http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html

```
$query = $this->EventCategory->find('all')
    ->select(['EventCategory.id', 'EventCategory.name'])
    ->where(['EventCategory.is_active' => 1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code in controller

```
$con=[];
$con['Users.role_id'] = 3;

  if (isset($this->request->query['keyword']) && !empty($this->request->query['keyword'])) {
            $keyword = trim($this->request->query['keyword']);
            $con['OR'] = ['Users.phone LIKE' => '%' . $keyword . '%', 'Users.name LIKE' => '%' . $keyword . '%', 'ContractorDetails.company_name LIKE' => '%' . $keyword . '%', 'ProjectTypes.name LIKE' => '%' . $keyword . '%'];
        }

 $this->paginate = [
            'sortWhitelist' => ['ContractorDetails.company_name', 'ProjectTypes.name', 'Users.name', 'Users.id', 'Users.phone', 'Users.deleted', 'Users.probationary'],
            'contain' => ['ContractorDetails.ProjectTypes'],
            'conditions' => $con,
            'order' => ['Users.id' => 'desc'],
            'limit' => (isset($this->request->query['limit'])) ? $this->request->query : 10,
        ];
        $users = $this->paginate($this->Users);

        $this->set(compact('users'));
```

user this in view.ctp

```
use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\I18n\Number;
    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="dataTables_info" id="editable_info" role="status" aria-live="polite"><?= $this->Paginator->counter(['format' => 'Showing {{start}} to {{end}} of {{count}} contractors']) ?></div>
                </div>
                <?php if ($this->Paginator->counter(['format' => '{{pages}}']) > 1) { ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_bootstrap" id="editable_paginate">
                            <ul class="pagination pull-right">
                                <?= $this->Paginator->prev('Previous') ?>
                                <?= $this->Paginator->numbers() ?>
                                <?= $this->Paginator->next('Next') ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
```